# upper bound for $z^3e^{z^2}-e^{3z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Can I possibly find an upper bound (possibly finite) for $$f(z)=z^3\exp(z^2)-\exp(3z^2)$$ on the closure of the ball (or disk) centered at the origin of radius $R>0?$

Or what i mean to say is that if I can find an upper bound for the $$\max_{z\in\bar{B(0,R)}}|f(z)|$$ which is finite?

Thanks!

Comment: The brutal estimate is $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant e^{3R^2} + e^{R^2}R^3$. The bound happens to be sharp, consider $z = -R$.

Comment: What do you mean "finite upper bound"? For any fixed $R$, it's finite. Since $f$ is unbounded on $\mathbb{C}$, you can't have a finite bound independent of $R$.